# Postgres get default real value of column (without datatype)

Tags: postgresql

How can one get just the default column value without it's datatype.

I'm creating a new enum type as:

```
CREATE TYPE t AS ENUM ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Then create a table as:

```
create table t1 (c1 t default 'a'::t);
```

When queering the column default either via information_schema or pg_* I get the response as text composed by the value and it's type concatenated to it:

```
# SELECT column_default::text 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE (table_schema, table_name, column_name)
    = ('public', 't1', 'c1');
 column_default 
----------------
 'a'::t
(1 row)

# SELECT d.adsrc AS default_value
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
LEFT   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d ON (a.attrelid, a.attnum)
                                     = (d.adrelid,  d.adnum)
WHERE  NOT a.attisdropped
    AND    a.attnum > 0
    AND    a.attrelid = 'public.t1'::regclass
    AND    a.attname = 'c1';
 default_value 
---------------
 'a'::t
(1 row)
```

I will need it to return **a** instead of **'a'::t**, exactly as I get when reading the enum values:

```
select UNNEST(ENUM_RANGE(NULL::t));
 unnest 
--------
 a
 b
 c
(3 rows)
```

I know I can trim/regex, but is there a pure PostgreSQL solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using string manipulation would be just fine, but maybe that pleases you better:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION default_to_t(arg IN text, res OUT t)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
$$BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || arg INTO res;
END;$$;
```

Then you can

```
SELECT default_to_t(d.adsrc) ...
```